# JSON parsing in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse JSON in JavaScript. If my JSON data looks like below, I want to iterate through all the JSON elements that start with "custom" and not with any other string. How do I do this?

```
{
    "fields": {
        "custom12": {
            value: "dsada"
        },
        "custom45": {
            value: "adsadad"
        },
        "test12": {
            value: "12323"
        }
    }
}​
```

Comment: Your json isn't valid, http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Shouldn't `fields` be an array?

Comment: @DaveNewton: No just straight key-value pairs unless they get nested data.

Comment: @Sarfraz Oops, yep, misread it--indentation (or lack of) threw me off.

Comment: Break down your task into subtasks. First, load up the JSON. Then, iterate through all properties. Then think about how to apply a filter (`if`, anybody?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var newObject = {}, key;
for(key in data.fields){
  if(key.search(/custom/) > -1){
    newObject[key] = data.fields[key];
  }
}
console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following iterates the `properties` of the `fields` object and checks whether the property's name contains `custom`:

```
var data = yourObjectLiteral, i, current;

for(i in data.fields) {
  if(i.indexOf('custom') > -1) {

    current = data.fields[i];

    // ... your logic ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the json string you provided I'd do it as such:

```
<script src="json2.js"></script>
<script>
var raw = '{'
+ ' "fields": {'
+ '  "custom12": {'
+ '   "value": "dsada"'
+ '  },'
+ '  "custom45": {'
+ '   "value": "adsadad"'
+ '  },'
+ '  "test12": {'
+ '   "value": "12323"'
+ '  }'
+ ' }'
+ '}';
var data = JSON.parse(raw);
var fields = data.fields;
var message = '';
for (var key in fields) {
    if (key.indexOf('custom') === 0) {
        message += key + ': ' + fields[key].value + '\n';
    }
}
alert(message);
</script>
```

But, if you can rewrite the incomming message a little it will look simpler.

```
<script src="json2.js"></script>
<script>
var raw = '{'
+ ' "custom12": "dsada",'
+ ' "custom45": "adsadad",'
+ ' "test12": "12323"'
+ '}';
var fields = JSON.parse(raw);
var message = '';
for (var key in fields) {
    if (key.indexOf('custom') === 0) {
        message += key + ': ' + fields[key] + '\n';
    }
}
alert(message);
</script>
```